# AngularJS needs to execute a function two times to show the results

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I have a navigation bar which has a drop-down menu item `Log Out` which calls the `ngPostLogOut()` function.

#### In app.js

```
.when("/logout", {
        controller: 'AuthController',
        templateUrl: "client/html/auth/logout.html"
    });
```

#### AuthController

```
$scope.ngPOSTLogOut = function() {
    if ($rootScope.user) {
        $rootScope.user = null;
    }
    if ($window.sessionStorage) {
        $window.sessionStorage.clear();
        alert('Entered..');
    }
    alert('Before HTTP');
    $http.post('server/auth/logout.php')
        .then(function(result) {
            $scope.logout = result.data;
        });
    alert('After HTTP');
    /*
    $timeout(function() {
        $location.path('/');
    }, 10000);
    */
};
```

#### logout.html

```
<div ng-controller="AuthController as auth">
<p ng-show='user == null' class="text-center">{{logout}}</p>
<br>
<button ng-click='ngPOSTLogOut()' class="btn btn-default btn-block">Angular To PHP</button>
```

Now, if a person clicks the `Log Out` item from the drop-down in the navbar then the function is called. I know this because I have set up alerts and they do pop up. But, the 'echo' from the login.php doesn't get featured. But, the odd thing is is that if I press the `Angular to PHP` button which also calls the `ngPostLogOut()` function, the function completes perfectly and as intended.

#### My guess

My guess is that `ngRoute` forces Angular to prioritize the HTML template switch making it so that the `ngPOSTLogOut()` function's parametres get ignored or dismissed.

The entire project on GitHub

https://github.com/AquaSolid/RAMA_Angular_PHP

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<li ng-click='ngPOSTLogOut()' ng-show='user != null'><a href="#logout">Log Out</a></li>
```

to this:

```
<li ng-show="user != null"><a ng-click="ngPOSTLogOut()">Log Out</a></li>
```

And consider using ng-if rather than ng-show.

Comment: I'd say that your suggestion works better,  but now the `logout.html` doesn't even show. I want it to show, to receive the `echo` from PHP and display it `{{logout}}`

Comment: So why not simply redirect to the logout page after promise is done? $scope.logout = result.data; $location.path('#logout/'); or something like this.

Comment: I tried that, it shows that HTML, but the main issue still remains. The `$http.post` still doesn't appear in `{{logout}}`. It only appears when the `Angular to PHP` button gets manually clicked.

Comment: Generally your backend shouldn't even send this kind of messages to frontend which is responsible to generate and show it. Backend should only send HTTP status code and/or DB data. So you should change {{logout}} to "You are now logged out", and remove these echos from PHP, 200 HTTP status is enough

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. I changed up my code to using a `$http.get` function with a `.success` and `.error` function, but the same problem prevails, the front-end data doesn't get updated, now the 'You have successfully logged out' comes from AngularJS, but again, only if the button `Angular to PHP` is clicked..